# Android - Displaying String Retrieved In an Async Task

Tags: android, string, dynamic, android-asynctask

I want to make an application that will grab the HTML from a website and display certain strings all inside the app in a linear layout. (I do not want to use webView). The data that I am retrieving changes every day; however the format is generally the same; different in only the amount of items on the page.

I am able to use jSoup (in an Async Task) to retrieve and parse the strings that I need. I also can make the string pop up in a toast message; so I can confirm that I am getting the string that I want.

My question is how I can actually display the strings in the app?

There are two different items I want to display. A name, and then a description below it.

Example:

(Name) FRENCH FRIED SHRIMP

(Description) Twelve shrimp lightly breaded with Japanese style bread crumbs and deep fried to golden brown. Served with cocktail sauce ONLY $12.49

Below is the Code that is currently displaying a string that I want.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        Toast.makeText(RoundtheClockActivity.this, doc.select("p").get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Right now I am going to want to change views to another page.. And I suppose String1 is what I want to display...  Code below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/soupSpecial1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:text="@string/string1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

To add, originally I have one view; but after I do the async task; I want to change to a new view. That will display the String.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                  new DownloadTask().execute("url");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logic for exception here
            }
```

Comment: View my answer in here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049136/get-string-from-asynctask-android/14049566#comment19413873_14049566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize your TextView in your app as below:

```
TextView txtSoup;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.yourDesiredLayout);
       ...
       ...
       ...

       txtSoup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soupSpecial);
   }
```

and in your Async Task's onPostExecute, do the following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
 setContentView(R.layout.yourNewLayout);
       txtSoup.setText(doc.select("p").get(0).toString());
    }
```

Comment: How should I declare the textview? Should it be declared in the OnCreateMethod? 
    TextView soupSpecial1 = new TextView(this);'

Comment: Yes declare in on create. You could also store the data in a SQLite database, or as an application preference.

Comment: I tried applying that code, but I get a Force Close when I click the button that I created that is supposed to trigger the change in text. Thanks for your help so far. (I added my Onclick method above)

Comment: This is the error that I get in the LogCat... 02-01 20:42:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(851): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I figured it out, by looking at one of your previous answers (to another question).
I was setting the text before I set the view. Once I did that, it worked fine. Thanks!