# Get String from asynctask android

Tags: android, jsoup, html-parser

How to get a string from AsyncTask? I use jsoup to retrieve content from the URL. In the case below, I've got the content, but I can't managed to put that content into the getItembody string. The code is:

```
    private String content;
    private static final String HTML_HEADER = "<html><body>";
    private static final String HTML_HEADER = "</body></html>";

    private void SetView(){ 
            contentsWebView.loadData(HTML_HEADER + getItemBody(item) + HTML_FOOTER,
            "text/html", "utf-8");
    }      

    private String getItemBody(Item item) {
        String body = "";
        new LoadContent().execute("");
        return body;
    }

    private class LoadContent extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                ViewItemActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = "http://inet.detik.com/read/2012/12/21/205518/2124977/398/dosen-unibraw-bikin-aplikasi-pengubah-suara-ketulisan";
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements element = doc.select(".text_detail");

                String content = element.toString();
                Log.v("LogContentView", content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return content;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("loading content...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

My question is I want the String content from doinbackground put in getItemBody string which string name is body, and I want to get result after dialog is closed. Current dialog does not close itself, but should be on tap key back. this is result from logcat Log.v("LogContentView", content);

```
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660): <div class="text_detail">
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  Malang - Indonesia memang memiliki developer aplikasi handal. Salah satunya dibuktikan Eko Sakti, dosen Universitas Brawijaya yang sukses menciptakan aplikasi di Windows Phone yang mampu membuat catatan tanpa harus menulis.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Never Write -- demikian nama aplikasi tersebut -- bisa dibilang baru di Indonesia. Kemampuannya adalah mengubah 
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <em>speech</em> (ucapan) bahasa Inggris menjadi bentuk teks. 
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Eko mengaku, ide pembuatan aplikasi ini berawal saat mengikuti program Summer School di Bali yang bentuk pengajarannya menggunakan bahasa Inggris.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />&quot;Waktu itu saya ikut Summer School dan dosen yang mengajar menggunakan bahasa Inggris. Saya mencoba mencatat mungkin karena terlalu cepat berbicaranya, banyak yang tertinggal. Setelah di rumah saya coba buka kembali catatan saya, malah tambah bingung,&quot; cerita Eko kepada wartawan di Universitas Brawijaya, Jumat (21/12/2012).
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Ditambahkannya, aplikasi Never Write bisa diupload di evernote. Selain itu aplikasi ini juga mempunyai kelebihan di antaranya bisa diakses di segala tempat dengan catatan file aplikasi sudah tersimpan pada perangkat genggam.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Never Write tidak mempunyai batasan dalam memasukkan jumlah kata. Sehingga bisa digunakan sebagai sub title film yang nantinya bisa diubah dalam bahasa Indonesia.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Sebagai bukti sahih kehebatannya, aplikasi ini pun sukses meraih gelar dalam kompetisi Nokia Lumia Apps Olympiad yang berlangsung dari pertengahan November 2012 lalu.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Dalam kompetisi tersebut terdapat 428 developer peserta dari sekitar 40 kampus yang tersebar di seluruh Indonesia.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Dari semuanya, terpilih 54 finalis dan 20 pemenang, dimana salah satunya adalah Eko Sakti.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />&quot;Salah satu pemilihan juri terhadap inovasi produk saya yaitu karena aplikasi yang saya ciptakan belum ada di pasaran. Penilaian yang lain juga ada pada fungsi atau kegunaan dari produk yang diciptakan,&quot; beber Eko. 
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <em>Nah</em>, setelah menang di ajang pembuatan aplikasi besutan Nokia tersebut, sang vendor asal Finlandia itu pun berencana untuk memasarkan aplikasi ciptaan Eko.
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:10.979: V/LogContentView(2660): </div>
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660): <div class="text_detail">
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  Malang - Indonesia memang memiliki developer aplikasi handal. Salah satunya dibuktikan Eko Sakti, dosen Universitas Brawijaya yang sukses menciptakan aplikasi di Windows Phone yang mampu membuat catatan tanpa harus menulis.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Never Write -- demikian nama aplikasi tersebut -- bisa dibilang baru di Indonesia. Kemampuannya adalah mengubah 
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <em>speech</em> (ucapan) bahasa Inggris menjadi bentuk teks. 
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Eko mengaku, ide pembuatan aplikasi ini berawal saat mengikuti program Summer School di Bali yang bentuk pengajarannya menggunakan bahasa Inggris.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />&quot;Waktu itu saya ikut Summer School dan dosen yang mengajar menggunakan bahasa Inggris. Saya mencoba mencatat mungkin karena terlalu cepat berbicaranya, banyak yang tertinggal. Setelah di rumah saya coba buka kembali catatan saya, malah tambah bingung,&quot; cerita Eko kepada wartawan di Universitas Brawijaya, Jumat (21/12/2012).
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Ditambahkannya, aplikasi Never Write bisa diupload di evernote. Selain itu aplikasi ini juga mempunyai kelebihan di antaranya bisa diakses di segala tempat dengan catatan file aplikasi sudah tersimpan pada perangkat genggam.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Never Write tidak mempunyai batasan dalam memasukkan jumlah kata. Sehingga bisa digunakan sebagai sub title film yang nantinya bisa diubah dalam bahasa Indonesia.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Sebagai bukti sahih kehebatannya, aplikasi ini pun sukses meraih gelar dalam kompetisi Nokia Lumia Apps Olympiad yang berlangsung dari pertengahan November 2012 lalu.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Dalam kompetisi tersebut terdapat 428 developer peserta dari sekitar 40 kampus yang tersebar di seluruh Indonesia.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />Dari semuanya, terpilih 54 finalis dan 20 pemenang, dimana salah satunya adalah Eko Sakti.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />&quot;Salah satu pemilihan juri terhadap inovasi produk saya yaitu karena aplikasi yang saya ciptakan belum ada di pasaran. Penilaian yang lain juga ada pada fungsi atau kegunaan dari produk yang diciptakan,&quot; beber Eko. 
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <em>Nah</em>, setelah menang di ajang pembuatan aplikasi besutan Nokia tersebut, sang vendor asal Finlandia itu pun berencana untuk memasarkan aplikasi ciptaan Eko.
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660):  <br />
12-27 10:12:40.059: V/LogContentView(2660): </div>
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178): <div class="text_detail">
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  Malang - Indonesia memang memiliki developer aplikasi handal. Salah satunya dibuktikan Eko Sakti, dosen Universitas Brawijaya yang sukses menciptakan aplikasi di Windows Phone yang mampu membuat catatan tanpa harus menulis.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Never Write -- demikian nama aplikasi tersebut -- bisa dibilang baru di Indonesia. Kemampuannya adalah mengubah 
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <em>speech</em> (ucapan) bahasa Inggris menjadi bentuk teks. 
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Eko mengaku, ide pembuatan aplikasi ini berawal saat mengikuti program Summer School di Bali yang bentuk pengajarannya menggunakan bahasa Inggris.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />&quot;Waktu itu saya ikut Summer School dan dosen yang mengajar menggunakan bahasa Inggris. Saya mencoba mencatat mungkin karena terlalu cepat berbicaranya, banyak yang tertinggal. Setelah di rumah saya coba buka kembali catatan saya, malah tambah bingung,&quot; cerita Eko kepada wartawan di Universitas Brawijaya, Jumat (21/12/2012).
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Ditambahkannya, aplikasi Never Write bisa diupload di evernote. Selain itu aplikasi ini juga mempunyai kelebihan di antaranya bisa diakses di segala tempat dengan catatan file aplikasi sudah tersimpan pada perangkat genggam.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Never Write tidak mempunyai batasan dalam memasukkan jumlah kata. Sehingga bisa digunakan sebagai sub title film yang nantinya bisa diubah dalam bahasa Indonesia.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Sebagai bukti sahih kehebatannya, aplikasi ini pun sukses meraih gelar dalam kompetisi Nokia Lumia Apps Olympiad yang berlangsung dari pertengahan November 2012 lalu.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Dalam kompetisi tersebut terdapat 428 developer peserta dari sekitar 40 kampus yang tersebar di seluruh Indonesia.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />Dari semuanya, terpilih 54 finalis dan 20 pemenang, dimana salah satunya adalah Eko Sakti.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />&quot;Salah satu pemilihan juri terhadap inovasi produk saya yaitu karena aplikasi yang saya ciptakan belum ada di pasaran. Penilaian yang lain juga ada pada fungsi atau kegunaan dari produk yang diciptakan,&quot; beber Eko. 
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <em>Nah</em>, setelah menang di ajang pembuatan aplikasi besutan Nokia tersebut, sang vendor asal Finlandia itu pun berencana untuk memasarkan aplikasi ciptaan Eko.
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178):  <br />
12-27 10:14:25.989: V/LogContentView(3178): </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code above variable body must be return from new LoadNews().execute("").get(), so you can change function getItemBody as below

```
private void SetView(){ 
        // move uri here, and you can dinamyc uri.
        String uri = "http://inet.detik.com/read/2012/12/21/205518/2124977/398/dosen-unibraw-bikin-aplikasi-pengubah-suara-ketulisan";
        contentsWebView.loadData(HTML_HEADER + getItemBody(uri) + HTML_FOOTER,
        "text/html", "utf-8");
}

private String getItemBody(String uri) {
    String body = null;
    try {
        body = new LoadContent().execute(uri).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return body;
}
```

and in class asynctask as below,

```
private class LoadContent extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            ViewItemActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements element = doc.select(".text_detail");

            content = element.toString();
            Log.v("LogContentView", content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return content;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("loading content...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

let me know if there is an error log.

Comment: I just had to change, please see. A few days ago i also made ​​the code like this.

Comment: thankyou very much Andy Unpam. Problem is solved with your code... Thanyouuuuu......

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it might help you to resolve your issue

```
    private String itemContent;
    private static final String HTML_HEADER = "<html><body>";
    private static final String HTML_HEADER = "</body></html>";
```

### In `onCreate()` method call `getItemBody(item)` method

```
    private void SetView(){ 
            contentsWebView.loadData(HTML_HEADER + itemContent + HTML_FOOTER,
            "text/html", "utf-8");
    }      

    private void getItemBody(String item) {
        new LoadContent().execute(item);
    }

    private class LoadContent extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                ViewItemActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = "http://inet.detik.com/read/2012/12/21/205518/2124977/398/dosen-unibraw-bikin-aplikasi-pengubah-suara-ketulisan";
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements element = doc.select(".text_detail");

                String content = element.toString();
                Log.v("LogContentView", content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return content;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("loading content...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Dialog.dismiss();
                    // You can get Item content from `doInBackgorund()` 
                    // to the  parameter result
                    itemContent = result;
                    SetView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thansk for reply, but i still get error, eclipse said, must be retrun string in method getItemBody.

Comment: If i view logcat in Log.v("LogContentView", content); get the result as html format, but in view android web view content show null.

Comment: this getItemBody(Item) doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = "http://inet.detik.com/read/2012/12/21/205518/2124977/398/dosen-unibraw-bikin-aplikasi-pengubah-suara-ketulisan";
            Document doc;
            String content = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements element = doc.select(".text_detail");

               content = element.toString();
                Log.v("LogContentView", content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but i want to String from return content in doinbackground as String body in method getItemBody.

Answer (score 0):

In your doInBackground, you return content and this content could be accessed in onPostExecute(). Try this:

```
  private String getItemBody(String passedContent) {
            String body = "";
if(passedContent != null && !passedContent.equals(""))
{
body = passedContent;
}
            new LoadContent().execute("");
            return body;
        }


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String url = "http://inet.detik.com/read/2012/12/21/205518/2124977/398/dosen-unibraw-bikin-aplikasi-pengubah-suara-ketulisan";
                Document doc;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    Elements element = doc.select(".text_detail");

                    String content = element.toString();
                    Log.v("LogContentView", content);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return content;
            }

    protected void onPostExecute(final String backgroundresult) {

    dialog.dismiss();

    String backgroundResult = backgroundresult;

    Stirng returnedString = getItemBody(backgroundResult); // But you are returning the same result over here and this makes the doInBackground() run again. 

    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply, still error in line String returnedString = getItemBody(String passedContent);

Comment: See the edit and let me know which error you get. Unless that, it is probably not possible to identify.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getItemBody(Item item) {
        String body = "";

        new LoadContent(){

              protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);//Dialog.dismiss();
                body = result;
              }
        }.execute("");

    // this should wait until asynchron completes:
        return body;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, still error in line body = result;, eclipse said String body must be final, and i have change to final, but still error in this line. but not show tips in eclipse